# Поиск по связанной таблице

Tags: php, yii2

yii2, есть модель поиска:

```
class ProductsBarcodesSearch extends ProductsBarcodes
{

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['barcode','product_id', 'code', 'name'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = ProductsBarcodes::find()->joinWith('product');

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        $query->andFilterWhere(['product_barcode.id' => $this->id]);

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product.name', $this->product_id])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product_barcode.barcode', $this->barcode]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

так все работает (поиск по имени из связанной таблицы), но стоит сделать так:

```
    $query
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product.name', $this->product_id])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product.code', $this->product_id]) //вот это добавил
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product_barcode.barcode', $this->barcode]);
```

и все ломается, перестает искать как по имени, так и по полю `code`

как правильно тянуть эти данные из связанной таблицы, чтобы работал поиск?

Comment: OrFilterWhere?)( просто догадка)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936611/yii2-how-to-use-orwhere-in-andwhere вот тут верный вариант записи

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, судя по названию метода поиск будет осуществляться по одному полю из n, а мне так не нужно.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, по ссылке немного не правильное решение, я сделал по-другому, и это работает. хотя странно то, что я делал так же и до написания вопроса, но это, почему-то, не сработало... может где-то опечатался...

Comment: Какие условия вы показали, такое решение и было предложено =) полагалось что вы знаете какие именно данные в таблице ищите =) 
 > andFilterWhere(['like', 'product.name', **$this->product_id]**)
 > andFilterWhere(['like', 'product.code',  **$this->product_id]**)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, это работало, но с 1 полем, с 2+ не работает.

Comment: Вы понимаете что искали в таблице "продукты" у которых одинаковый `product.code` и `product.name`, и если таких продуктов у вас нету - ничего не выводилось.. поэтому я и предположил что вы хотите искать  совпадение не в обоих полях - а в одном из них(что логично и часто востребовано), если же вы хотели искать разные данные в этих полях - стоило это делать изначально

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, да, сейчас я понял это, и цель изначально была другая, но так как я не знал тогда (до добавления вопроса), как это реализовать, написал так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нашел решение.

1. нужно добавить новые свойства классу:

   ```
   class ProductsBarcodesSearch extends ProductsBarcodes
   {
       public $pname;
       public $pcode;
   ```
2. задать значение, по которому будут искаться данные:

   ```
       ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product.name', $this->pname])
       ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product.code', $this->pcode])
   ```
3. прописать во `view` в атрибутах эти свойства

   ```
       [
           'attribute' => 'pcode',
           'label' => 'Внутренний код',
           'value' => function($model){
               if ($model->product_id){
                   return $model->product->code;
               }
               return 'Нет кода';
           }
       ],
       [
           'attribute' => 'pname',
           'label' => 'Название продукта',
           'format' => 'html',
           'value' => function($model){
               if ($model->product_id){
                   return Html::a($model->product->name, \yii\helpers\Url::to(['/products/view?id=' . $model->product->id]));
               }
               return 'Нет имени';
           }
       ],
   ```

единственное что я пока не пока как сделать, это сортировка по этим полям.
если знаете как реализовать, напишите.

Comment: Сортировка : `->orderBy(['product.name' => SORT_ASC, 'product.code' => SORT_DESC]);`